# Regex to match asterisks, tildes, dashes and square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to write a regex to match asterisks, tildes, dashes and square brackets.

What I have:

```js
const str = "The] quick [brown] fox **jumps** over ~~the~~ lazy dog --- in the [woods";
console.log(str.match(/[^\]][^\[\]]*\]?|\]/g));
// [
//     "The]",
//     " quick ",
//     "[brown]",
//     " fox **jumps** over ~~the~~ lazy dog --- in the ",
//     "[woods"
// ];
```

What I want:

```
[
    "The]",
    " quick ",
    "[brown]",
    " fox ",
    "**jumps**",
    " over ",
    "~~the~~",
    " lazy dog ",
    "---",
    " in the ",
    "[woods"
];
```

**Edit:**

Some more examples/combinations of the string are:

```
"The] quick brown fox jumps [over] the lazy [dog"
// [ "The]", " quick brown fox jumps ", "[over]", " the lazy ", "[dog" ]


"The~~ quick brown fox jumps [over] the lazy **dog"
// [ "The~~", " quick brown fox jumps ", "[over]", " the lazy ", "**dog" ]
```

**Edit 2:**

I know this is crazy but:

```
"The special~~ quick brown fox jumps [over the] lazy **dog on** a **Sunday night."
// [ "The special~~", " quick brown fox jumps ", "[over the]", " lazy ", "**dog on**", " a ", "**Sunday night" ]
```

Comment: You also want to match spaces?

Comment: Your regex doesn't seem to have anything to match characters other than square brackets, from what I can see? That's why it won't break up the string `" fox **jumps** over ~~the~~ lazy dog --- in the "`. Try testing breaking apart just that string, then combine the regex expressions one at a time as you parse more characters.

Comment: It seems like what you're trying to do is come up with a markup language of sorts?  If so, you might want to consider a state machine approach over regular expressions.

Comment: @Barmar yeah... I'm trying to match spaces too

Comment: @c1moore You are correct. It is a markup language I'm dealing with. I've never heard of state machine approach. Will definitely look into it. Thanks!!

Comment: The problem with regular expressions with mark up languages is that they tend not to be regular, so Finite State Machines tend to be better suited.  I haven't read it (or even scanned over it), but something like this should get you started: https://medium.com/@brianray_7981/tutorial-write-a-finite-state-machine-to-parse-a-custom-language-in-pure-python-1c11ade9bd43

Comment: @SrikanthBandaru If you want to parse a markup language then using regex might not be the right way.

Comment: So... `[ ]` is supposed to be a marker for the link. `[over` and `the]` works fine coz both of them have `square brackets` and I can use it to style those as links. But I cannot have `The special~~` as `The ` and `special~~` because `The ` doesn't have any markers to identify it is a `strike off text`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with more alternations to include your desired matches:

```js
const re = /\[[^\[\]\n]*\]|\b\w+\]|\[\w+|\*\*.+?(?:\*\*|$)|-+|(?:^|~~).+?~~|[\w ]+/mg;
const arr = [
'The special~~ quick brown fox jumps [over the] lazy **dog on** a **Sunday night.',
'The] quick brown fox jumps [over] the lazy [dog',
'The] quick [brown] fox **jumps** over ~~the~~ lazy dog --- in the [woods'
];

var n;
arr.forEach( str => {
  m = str.match(re);
  console.log(m);
});
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ImqZmI/1)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear in my question. I just edited it to reflect a few more examples of strings I'm dealing with.

Comment: Thank you for the response, https://regex101.com/r/rumQsU/2 in this scenario, how to get `~~The quick brown fox jumps ` as the first match instead of `~` as first and `~The quick brown fox jumps ` as second without losing the current behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to split the string. It splits the string on text between one of the delimiters (`**`, `~~` or `[]`) and either a matching delimiter or the start/end of the string; or on a sequence of hyphens (`-`). It uses a capture group to ensure the string matched by the regex appears in the output array:

```
((?:\*\*|^)[A-Za-z. ]+(?:\*\*|$)|(?:~~|^)[A-Za-z. ]+(?:~~|$)|(?:\[|^)[A-Za-z. ]+(?:\]|$)|-+
```

```js
const re = /((?:\*\*|^)[A-Za-z. ]+(?:\*\*|$)|(?:~~|^)[A-Za-z. ]+(?:~~|$)|(?:\[|^)[A-Za-z. ]+(?:\]|$)|-+)/;
const str = [
  'The] quick [brown] fox **jumps** over ~~the~~ lazy dog --- in the [woods',
  'The] quick brown fox jumps [over] the lazy [dog',
  'The~~ quick brown fox jumps [over] the lazy **dog',
  'The special~~ quick brown fox jumps [over the] lazy **dog on** a **Sunday night.'];

str.forEach(v => console.log(v.split(re).filter(Boolean)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```